# Trimming A Vertical Bar

Tags: php, string

In PHP the trim function has a parameter for trimming specific characters (handy for leading zeros and the like). I can't seem to get it to accept a vertical bar (|) character. Anyone know how to get this working? I tried the hex value but had no luck. I'm sure it's something simple.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me:

```
var_dump(trim('|foo|', '|')); // string 'foo' (length=3)
```

Maybe you have some whitespace around it, or your're using the wrong pipe character? `¦` vs `|`

Comment: I thought you might have been on to something with the wrong pipe char, but trying this:
echo trim(substr($response, strpos($response,'AF')+2),'#¦|');
still results in this: You do not have any fee needed to pay.|

Comment: I copied & pasted your string but it still worked. Can you var_dump(substr($response, strpos($response,'AF')+2));

Comment: The var_dump gave: string(41) "#You do not have any fee needed to pay.| ", so I added in a white space character with no luck:
echo trim(substr($response, strpos($response,'AF')+2),'#¦|\ ');

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$str = "|test string";
echo trim($str, "|");

test string
```

Can you show some of your code?

Maybe you want to remove a | in the middle of a string
you can use [str_replace](http://us.php.net/str_replace)

```
str_replace("|", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo trim('|text|', '|'); // returns text
```

The second param was added in PHP 4.1!

Answer (score 0):

[`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string. If you'd like to replace characters in the middle of a string, use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace), or [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) if you like regular expressions.